# Ubuntu 17.10: Doesn't detect my external monitor in my HDMI port anymore

Tags: multiple-monitors, 17.10

For some reason, my laptop doesn't detect my external monitor anymore.  It all used to work fine.  I've plugged both a projector and a monitor through a KVM with no problems either way.

I was playing around with Wine and PlayOnLinux trying to get something to work.  I installed a few 32-bit packages to try to get the program working.  When I rebooted, XWindows wouldn't even start.  I've managed to reinstall gdm3 and I've installed and uninstalled the nvidia drivers a few times.  At the moment, I have bumblebee installed.

Here's how how I got things working so far:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall gdm3
```

Xrandr output:

```
$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
eDP1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 380mm x 210mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  59.93    48.07  
.....
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

It doesn't matter how many times I plug and unplug the HDMI cord, it still says disconnected.  I've also tried bypassing the KVM with no success.  I have also looked in the Settings, and only see a single monitor.  When I had the nvidia driver installed, the nvidia settings didn't detect it either.

lspci output:

```
$ lspci | grep -i vga
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 520 (rev 07)
00:13.0 Non-VGA unclassified device: Intel Corporation Device 9d35 (rev 21)
$ lspci | grep -i nvidia
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM108M [GeForce 940MX] (rev ff)
```

I am using X11 instead of Wayland:

```
$ echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE
x11
```

I'm using the generic kernel.  I read some people had issues with the low latency.

```
$ uname -a
Linux cashew 4.13.0-25-generic #29-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jan 8 21:14:41 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Ubuntu version:

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 17.10
Release:    17.10
Codename:   artful
```

Any clues on what else I can do to troubleshoot?

**Update**:  It actually just started working for me.  I'm wondering if it was a package update that broke it and now fixed it.

Looking at /var/log/apt/history.log ...

```
Start-Date: 2018-01-09  06:29:01
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Upgrade: poppler-utils:amd64 (0.57.0-2ubuntu4.1, 0.57.0-2ubuntu4.2), libpoppler-qt5-1:amd64 (0.57.0-2ubuntu4.1, 0.57.0-2ubuntu4.2), libpoppler-glib8:amd64 (0.57.0-2ubuntu4.1, 0.57.0-2ubuntu4.2), libpoppler68:amd64 (0.57.0-2ubuntu4.1, 0.57.0-2ubuntu4.2)
End-Date: 2018-01-09  06:29:03

Start-Date: 2018-01-10  17:11:53
Commandline: packagekit role='install-packages'
Requested-By: skp (1000)
Install: python-wxgtk3.0:amd64 (3.0.2.0+dfsg-5, automatic), mesa-utils:amd64 (8.3.0-5, automatic), icoutils:amd64 (0.31.3-1, automatic), python-wxversion:amd64 (3.0.2.0+dfsg-5, automatic), playonlinux:amd64 (4.2.12-1)
End-Date: 2018-01-10  17:12:07

Start-Date: 2018-01-10  21:11:41
Commandline: apt-get install p11-kit:i386
Requested-By: skp (1000)
Install: p11-kit:i386 (0.23.7-3), p11-kit-modules:i386 (0.23.7-3, automatic)
Remove: gnome-keyring:amd64 (3.20.1-1ubuntu1), chrome-gnome-shell:amd64 (9-0ubuntu1), seahorse:amd64 (3.20.0-3.1), p11-kit:amd64 (0.23.7-3), ubuntu-session:amd64 (3.26.1-0ubuntu6), ubuntu-desktop:amd64 (1.404.1), evolution-data-server:amd64 (3.26.1-1ubuntu1), gdm3:amd64 (3.26.1-3ubuntu3), gnome-shell:amd64 (3.26.2-0ubuntu0.1)
End-Date: 2018-01-10  21:11:46

Start-Date: 2018-01-10  21:17:18
Commandline: apt-get upgrade
Requested-By: skp (1000)
Upgrade: wine-devel-amd64:amd64 (3.0~rc4~artful, 3.0~rc5~artful), wine-devel:amd64 (3.0~rc4~artful, 3.0~rc5~artful), linux-libc-dev:amd64 (4.13.0-21.24, 4.13.0-25.29), google-chrome-stable:amd64 (63.0.3239.108-1, 63.0.3239.132-1), skypeforlinux:amd64 (8.11.0.4, 8.13.0.2), winehq-devel:amd64 (3.0~rc4~artful, 3.0~rc5~artful), wine-devel-i386:i386 (3.0~rc4~artful, 3.0~rc5~artful)
End-Date: 2018-01-10  21:17:51

Start-Date: 2018-01-10  21:21:35
Commandline: apt-get install libp11-kit-gnome-keyring:i386
Requested-By: skp (1000)
Install: libp11-kit-gnome-keyring:i386 (3.20.1-1ubuntu1)
End-Date: 2018-01-10  21:21:36

Start-Date: 2018-01-10  21:26:42
Commandline: apt-get autoremove
Requested-By: skp (1000)
Remove: libieee1284-3:i386 (0.2.11-13), wine64-development:amd64 (2.18-1), linux-image-extra-4.13.0-17-generic:amd64 (4.13.0-17.20), wine32-development:i386 (2.18-1), libwine-development:amd64 (2.18-1), libwine-development:i386 (2.18-1), fonts-wine:amd64 (2.0.2-2ubuntu1), ocl-icd-libopencl1:i386 (2.2.11-1ubuntu1)
End-Date: 2018-01-10  21:27:02

Start-Date: 2018-01-10  22:24:15
Commandline: apt-get upgrade
Requested-By: skp (1000)
Upgrade: code:amd64 (1.19.1-1513676564, 1.19.2-1515599945)
End-Date: 2018-01-10  22:24:33

Start-Date: 2018-01-10  22:24:54
Commandline: apt-get dist-upgrade
Requested-By: skp (1000)
Install: linux-image-4.13.0-25-generic:amd64 (4.13.0-25.29, automatic), linux-signed-image-4.13.0-25-generic:amd64 (4.13.0-25.29, automatic), linux-headers-4.13.0-25:amd64 (4.13.0-25.29, automatic), linux-image-extra-4.13.0-25-generic:amd64 (4.13.0-25.29, automatic), linux-headers-4.13.0-25-generic:amd64 (4.13.0-25.29, automatic)
Upgrade: linux-headers-generic:amd64 (4.13.0.21.22, 4.13.0.25.26), linux-image-generic:amd64 (4.13.0.21.22, 4.13.0.25.26), linux-signed-image-generic:amd64 (4.13.0.21.22, 4.13.0.25.26), linux-signed-generic:amd64 (4.13.0.21.22, 4.13.0.25.26), linux-generic:amd64 (4.13.0.21.22, 4.13.0.25.26)
End-Date: 2018-01-10  22:26:02

Start-Date: 2018-01-10  23:13:32
Commandline: apt-get purge nvidia-*
Requested-By: skp (1000)
Purge: nvidia-prime:amd64 (), nvidia-opencl-icd-384:amd64 (), nvidia-384:amd64 (), nvidia-settings:amd64 ()
End-Date: 2018-01-10  23:13:54

Start-Date: 2018-01-10  23:14:12
Commandline: apt-get autoremove
Requested-By: skp (1000)
Remove: linux-signed-image-4.13.0-19-generic:amd64 (4.13.0-19.22), linux-image-extra-4.13.0-19-generic:amd64 (4.13.0-19.22), linux-headers-4.13.0-19-generic:amd64 (4.13.0-19.22), linux-headers-4.13.0-19:amd64 (4.13.0-19.22), linux-image-4.13.0-19-generic:amd64 (4.13.0-19.22)
End-Date: 2018-01-10  23:14:40

Start-Date: 2018-01-10  23:20:51
Commandline: apt-get install nvidia-384
Requested-By: skp (1000)
Install: libunity-settings-daemon1:amd64 (15.04.1+17.10.20171003-0ubuntu1, automatic), gnome-keyring:amd64 (3.20.1-1ubuntu1, automatic), indicator-common:amd64 (16.10.0+16.10.20160913-0ubuntu1, automatic), libfcitx-gclient0:amd64 (1:4.2.9.1-6, automatic), libcuda1-384:amd64 (384.111-0ubuntu0.17.10.1, automatic), p11-kit:amd64 (0.23.7-3, automatic), indicator-sound:amd64 (12.10.2+17.10.20170829.1-0ubuntu1, automatic), indicator-keyboard:amd64 (0.0.0+17.10.20170906-0ubuntu1, automatic), evolution-data-server:amd64 (3.26.1-1ubuntu1, automatic), ubuntu-touch-sounds:amd64 (15.08, automatic), dkms:amd64 (2.3-3ubuntu3, automatic), nvidia-prime:amd64 (0.8.5, automatic), unity-greeter:amd64 (17.10.0-0ubuntu1, automatic), indicator-session:amd64 (17.3.20+17.10.20171006-0ubuntu1, automatic), libfcitx-config4:amd64 (1:4.2.9.1-6, automatic), geoclue-ubuntu-geoip:amd64 (1.0.2+14.04.20131125-0ubuntu3, automatic), libxnvctrl0:amd64 (387.22-0ubuntu0~gpu17.10.1, automatic), lib32gcc1:amd64 (1:7.2.0-8ubuntu3, automatic), geoclue:amd64 (0.12.99-4ubuntu2, automatic), libc6-i386:amd64 (2.26-0ubuntu2, automatic), indicator-datetime:amd64 (15.10+17.10.20170829.2-0ubuntu1, automatic), libgeoclue0:amd64 (0.12.99-4ubuntu2, automatic), libaccounts-glib0:amd64 (1.23+17.04.20161104-0ubuntu1, automatic), screen-resolution-extra:amd64 (0.17.1, automatic), libfcitx-utils0:amd64 (1:4.2.9.1-6, automatic), indicator-application:amd64 (12.10.1+17.04.20161201-0ubuntu1, automatic), libido3-0.1-0:amd64 (13.10.0+17.04.20161028-0ubuntu1, automatic), unity-settings-daemon:amd64 (15.04.1+17.10.20171003-0ubuntu1, automatic), indicator-applet:amd64 (12.10.2+17.10.20170425-0ubuntu1, automatic), indicator-power:amd64 (12.10.6+17.10.20170829.1-0ubuntu3, automatic), bbswitch-dkms:amd64 (0.8-4ubuntu1, automatic), nvidia-opencl-icd-384:amd64 (384.111-0ubuntu0.17.10.1, automatic), lightdm:amd64 (1.24.0-0ubuntu1, automatic), nvidia-384:amd64 (384.111-0ubuntu0.17.10.1), liblightdm-gobject-1-0:amd64 (1.24.0-0ubuntu1, automatic), indicator-messages:amd64 (13.10.1+17.04.20170120-0ubuntu2, automatic), liburl-dispatcher1:amd64 (0.1+17.04.20170328-0ubuntu3, automatic), nvidia-settings:amd64 (387.22-0ubuntu0~gpu17.10.1, automatic), libpanel-applet3:amd64 (1:3.24.1-1ubuntu2, automatic)
Remove: p11-kit:i386 (0.23.7-3)
End-Date: 2018-01-10  23:22:13

Start-Date: 2018-01-10  23:28:03
Commandline: apt-get remove unity-greeter
Requested-By: skp (1000)
Remove: unity-greeter:amd64 (17.10.0-0ubuntu1)
End-Date: 2018-01-10  23:28:05

Start-Date: 2018-01-10  23:36:05
Commandline: apt-get install --reinstall gdm3
Requested-By: skp (1000)
Install: ubuntu-session:amd64 (3.26.1-0ubuntu6, automatic), gdm3:amd64 (3.26.1-3ubuntu3), gnome-shell:amd64 (3.26.2-0ubuntu0.1, automatic)
End-Date: 2018-01-10  23:36:09

Start-Date: 2018-01-11  08:13:49
Commandline: apt-get purge nvidia-*
Requested-By: skp (1000)
Purge: libcuda1-384:amd64 (384.111-0ubuntu0.17.10.1), nvidia-prime:amd64 (0.8.5), nvidia-opencl-icd-384:amd64 (384.111-0ubuntu0.17.10.1), nvidia-384:amd64 (384.111-0ubuntu0.17.10.1), nvidia-settings:amd64 (387.22-0ubuntu0~gpu17.10.1)
End-Date: 2018-01-11  08:14:25

Start-Date: 2018-01-11  08:14:38
Commandline: apt-get autoremove
Requested-By: skp (1000)
Remove: libunity-settings-daemon1:amd64 (15.04.1+17.10.20171003-0ubuntu1), libfcitx-gclient0:amd64 (1:4.2.9.1-6), indicator-sound:amd64 (12.10.2+17.10.20170829.1-0ubuntu1), indicator-keyboard:amd64 (0.0.0+17.10.20170906-0ubuntu1), ubuntu-touch-sounds:amd64 (15.08), dkms:amd64 (2.3-3ubuntu3), p11-kit-modules:i386 (0.23.7-3), indicator-session:amd64 (17.3.20+17.10.20171006-0ubuntu1), libfcitx-config4:amd64 (1:4.2.9.1-6), geoclue-ubuntu-geoip:amd64 (1.0.2+14.04.20131125-0ubuntu3), libxnvctrl0:amd64 (387.22-0ubuntu0~gpu17.10.1), lib32gcc1:amd64 (1:7.2.0-8ubuntu3), geoclue:amd64 (0.12.99-4ubuntu2), libc6-i386:amd64 (2.26-0ubuntu2), indicator-datetime:amd64 (15.10+17.10.20170829.2-0ubuntu1), libgeoclue0:amd64 (0.12.99-4ubuntu2), libaccounts-glib0:amd64 (1.23+17.04.20161104-0ubuntu1), screen-resolution-extra:amd64 (0.17.1), libfcitx-utils0:amd64 (1:4.2.9.1-6), libido3-0.1-0:amd64 (13.10.0+17.04.20161028-0ubuntu1), unity-settings-daemon:amd64 (15.04.1+17.10.20171003-0ubuntu1), indicator-applet:amd64 (12.10.2+17.10.20170425-0ubuntu1), indicator-power:amd64 (12.10.6+17.10.20170829.1-0ubuntu3), bbswitch-dkms:amd64 (0.8-4ubuntu1), lightdm:amd64 (1.24.0-0ubuntu1), liblightdm-gobject-1-0:amd64 (1.24.0-0ubuntu1), indicator-messages:amd64 (13.10.1+17.04.20170120-0ubuntu2), liburl-dispatcher1:amd64 (0.1+17.04.20170328-0ubuntu3), libpanel-applet3:amd64 (1:3.24.1-1ubuntu2)
End-Date: 2018-01-11  08:14:43

Start-Date: 2018-01-11  08:54:41
Commandline: apt install dkms
Requested-By: skp (1000)
Install: dkms:amd64 (2.3-3ubuntu3)
End-Date: 2018-01-11  08:54:43

Start-Date: 2018-01-11  09:02:27
Commandline: apt-get install bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia primus linux-headers-generic
Requested-By: skp (1000)
Install: libcuda1-304:amd64 (304.137-0ubuntu1, automatic), primus-libs:amd64 (0~20150328-4, automatic), primus-libs:i386 (0~20150328-4, automatic), bumblebee-nvidia:amd64 (3.2.1-16), primus:amd64 (0~20150328-4), libxnvctrl0:amd64 (387.22-0ubuntu0~gpu17.10.1, automatic), lib32gcc1:amd64 (1:7.2.0-8ubuntu3, automatic), primus-libs-ia32:i386 (0~20150328-4, automatic), nvidia-current:amd64 (304.137-0ubuntu1, automatic), libc6-i386:amd64 (2.26-0ubuntu2, automatic), screen-resolution-extra:amd64 (0.17.1, automatic), bumblebee:amd64 (3.2.1-16), bbswitch-dkms:amd64 (0.8-4ubuntu1, automatic), nvidia-opencl-icd-304:amd64 (304.137-0ubuntu1, automatic), nvidia-304:amd64 (304.137-0ubuntu1, automatic), socat:amd64 (1.7.3.2-1, automatic), nvidia-settings:amd64 (387.22-0ubuntu0~gpu17.10.1, automatic)
End-Date: 2018-01-11  09:03:29

Start-Date: 2018-01-11  19:53:28
Commandline: apt install ubuntu-desktop^
Requested-By: skp (1000)
Install: seahorse:amd64 (3.20.0-3.1), ubuntu-desktop:amd64 (1.404.1)
End-Date: 2018-01-11  19:53:31

Start-Date: 2018-01-11  20:29:27
Commandline: apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg
Requested-By: skp (1000)
Reinstall: xserver-xorg:amd64 (1:7.7+19ubuntu3)
End-Date: 2018-01-11  20:29:28

Start-Date: 2018-01-11  20:54:40
Commandline: apt-get install chrome-gnome-shell
Requested-By: skp (1000)
Install: chrome-gnome-shell:amd64 (9-0ubuntu1)
End-Date: 2018-01-11  20:54:41

Start-Date: 2018-01-11  21:07:50
Commandline: aptdaemon role='role-commit-packages' sender=':1.116'
Install: libcuda1-387:amd64 (387.34-0ubuntu0~gpu17.10.2, automatic), nvidia-opencl-icd-387:amd64 (387.34-0ubuntu0~gpu17.10.2, automatic), nvidia-387:amd64 (387.34-0ubuntu0~gpu17.10.2)
Remove: libcuda1-304:amd64 (304.137-0ubuntu1), nvidia-current:amd64 (304.137-0ubuntu1), nvidia-opencl-icd-304:amd64 (304.137-0ubuntu1), nvidia-304:amd64 (304.137-0ubuntu1)
End-Date: 2018-01-11  21:09:27

Start-Date: 2018-01-11  21:41:03
Commandline: apt-get purge nvidia-*
Purge: libcuda1-387:amd64 (387.34-0ubuntu0~gpu17.10.2), bumblebee-nvidia:amd64 (3.2.1-16), nvidia-opencl-icd-304:amd64 (), nvidia-opencl-icd-387:amd64 (387.34-0ubuntu0~gpu17.10.2), nvidia-304:amd64 (), nvidia-387:amd64 (387.34-0ubuntu0~gpu17.10.2), nvidia-settings:amd64 (387.22-0ubuntu0~gpu17.10.1)
End-Date: 2018-01-11  21:41:41

Start-Date: 2018-01-11  22:49:03
Commandline: apt install freeipmi-tools
Requested-By: skp (1000)
Install: libfreeipmi16:amd64 (1.4.11-1.1ubuntu4, automatic), libipmidetect0:amd64 (1.4.11-1.1ubuntu4, automatic), freeipmi-common:amd64 (1.4.11-1.1ubuntu4, automatic), libipmiconsole2:amd64 (1.4.11-1.1ubuntu4, automatic), freeipmi-tools:amd64 (1.4.11-1.1ubuntu4)
End-Date: 2018-01-11  22:49:05

Start-Date: 2018-01-11  22:54:09
Commandline: apt install ipmitool
Requested-By: skp (1000)
Install: ipmitool:amd64 (1.8.18-4), openipmi:amd64 (2.0.22-1.1ubuntu1, automatic), libopenipmi0:amd64 (2.0.22-1.1ubuntu1, automatic)
End-Date: 2018-01-11  22:54:12
```